# Gson Java reserved keyword

Tags: java, gson, keyword

I have some JSON that I am deserializing using Gson.

```
{
"resp": {
"posts": [
  {
    ...
    "public": true,
    ...
  }] 
}
```

My problem is that `public` is a Java keyword, so how would I make a field in my class that correlates with the `public` field in the JSON?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You could use a different name for your field, using gson's [Field Naming Support](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-JSON-Field-Naming-Support).

```
public class Post {
    @SerializedName("public")
    private boolean isPublic;
    ...
}
```

Comment: You save my night!

Answer (score 3):

Worth a quick note that you need to include gson.annotations or SerializedName for this to compile as not part of the base gson.Gson package:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
```