# Java, a way to use reserved words

Tags: java, variables, keyword, names

Is there a method that allows you to use a keyword as a resource name in Java similar to the method used in C# of adding @ to the start of the word?

I found some posts asking this a few years ago and it wasn't possible then.  Was it possibly added though in Java 7 or may be added in Java 8?

Reasons for doing this are very scarce.  For me though I've encountered it when deserializing large json objects that use the keywords as variable names.  A particular json object I'm working with uses throw.  In C# I'd just add "string @throw" into my class that I use to deserialize the object.  The only methods I can find to do this in java would require a streaming deserialization which would be a major pain, or string parsing with Regular Expressions both of which seem to be a lot of work for what could otherwise be a super simple task.

Comment: So, is your question really about the JSON library yiu are using, rather than Java itself? How that library handles reserved names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible in Java. The names of variables 
in Java cannot coincide with any **keywords** or **reserved words**. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Comment: That is the answer to my question sure enough.  Thankfully due to this site I just found a simple work around to my issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258796/gson-java-reserved-keyword?rq=1

Comment: @Jazzeroki Thanks, that's a nice and useful workaround indeed.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible by using GSON's [Field Naming Support](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-JSON-Field-Naming-Support)

eg.

```
 @SerializedName("new")
    private String New;
   public String getNew ()
    {
        return New;
    }
    public void setNew (String aNew)
    {
        New = aNew;
    }
```